# Water Hammer Arrester Shutting off Water

Tags: washing-machine, water-hammer

**Problem**

Everything was working fine for about 3 years. However, recently my LG top-load washer has been occasionally stopping in the middle of a cycle and showing an IE error stating the washer was unable to fill with water.

**Findings**

Through some trial and error I have consistently been able to get the water flowing again by turning off the the water from the valve on the water hammer arrester and then *slowly* turning the valve back to the on position and it instantly starts filling with water again.

So is it possible the water hammer arrester is somehow faulty and "freezing up" causing it to block water flow to the washer? But once I relieve pressure by shutting off the valve it resets? Not too familiar with how these devices work.

**Stats**

- I have checked and cleaned the input filters, they are good.
- Water hammer brand is [Ayrlett®](http://www.ayrlett.com/water-hammer-arresters)
- LG washing machine model: LG WT1201C/WT1101C
- Washer is less than 4 years old
- Apartment is also less than 4 years old
- The hot water input is fine just the cold water one "freezes up"
- I live in a warm environment in an apartment

Comment: Are both shutoff valves completely open, or is one open more than the other?

Comment: I am super confused. Water hammer arrestors go on dead-end branches by nature, *they have no capability whatsoever* to interrupt water flow...  and no reason to have a valve.  Are you instead referring to the *water supply valve* to your washing machine, which may be in a package [such as this](http://amzn.to/2vhG6V4) which also (unrelated) includes water hammer arrestors?

Comment: I could be wrong, but do your water hammer arrestors need replaced? They do have a limited life span.

Comment: I have never used water hammer arrestors with a washing machine and have not noticed an audible water hammer. I am operating on the (admittedly unconfirmed) assumption that good quality clothes washers have "soft close" valves which reduce water hammer to insignificance. In contrast, for a time I was using a base model shutoff timer on an outside faucet and it gave a terrific water hammer detected on the kitchen faucet.

Comment: Sorry @Harper I explained improperly, you are correct. The water supply valve.

Comment: @mmathis yes both appear to be open

Comment: I need to do some more investigating. I'm going to get it to lock up again. Then try disconnecting the supply hose to see if water is in fact flowing to the machine to rule out possibilities.

Comment: Is it possible the filter screens are plugged? Turning off the water allows the crud to move and water flows again for a while? Some screens are close to the solenoid on the machine some by the supply valve.

Answer (score 1):

You might have supply hoses that have an internal shutoff valve in one end which closes if the flow rate is too large. These are designed as protection against a ruptured hose. One brand is Watts FloodSafe(tm) supply hoses.

If you have these, one might be malfunctioning or connected backwards. This type is unidirectional; the end with the control valve must be connected to the water supply. Standard hoses will work no matter which end is connected to the water supply.

I have a set of Watts FloodSafe hoses in a cabinet, but I have not tried to install them on our new "smart" top loader. I had installed them on the washer of an elderly neighbor, but he was dissatisfied with them because his washer was taking too long to fill. I removed them and put in the standard hoses. It is possible that some of the new washers have sensors to detect low flow. Your washer might be detecting low flow and is programmed to shut off and report an error.

Comment: Doesn't appear so.